# Unable to work with interface imported from another pkg, says method is missing but its there

Tags: go

I'm unable to work with an interface imported from another package and not sure what I should do. Example code:

```
var inner types.TxData // <-- interface imported from types package
inner = &InternalTx{
        ChainId: (*big.Int)(dec.ChainID),
        Data:    *dec.Data,
    }
```

Out of all the methods listed in the interface, 1 method is not accepted:
func (tx *InternalTx) accessList() types.AccessList { return nil }

Go complains that InternalTx does not implement accessList() to satisfy types.TxData interface, but if i capitalise accessList() to Accesslist() then I get another complaint stating that :

have AccessList() types.AccessList
want accessList() types.AccessList

So i'm very confused what I need to do here?

Edit:

I've implemented also the following based on recent suggestion:

```
type TxData struct {
    types.TxData
}
var inner TxData

internalTx := &InternalTx{
ChainId: (*big.Int)(dec.ChainID),
        Data:    *dec.Data,
}
inner = TxData{TxData: internalTx}
```

Issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

If an interface is declared with an unexported method (such as `accessList`), then you cannot implement that interface in another package, because that name is not exported. This is a common way to force you to use implementations in the original package.

One way to deal with this is to embed that interface, and then delegate functionality to an implementation of it:

```
type TxData struct {
   types.TxData
}

someImplementation:=// Get an implementation of types.TxData
inner:=TxData{TxData: someImplementation}
```

This will use the `accessList` of `someImplementation`.

Comment: I followed your suggestion (see my edit to original post) but issue still persists.

Comment: I think i understand what you are saying, but that someImplementation is a struct that's declared on my package  (InternalTx  is declared in my package)  and not on the package that contains types.TxData interface..

Comment: Because of the unexported method, you cannot implement that interface outside that package. You have to do that same thing for InternalTx

Comment: I understand. I do find it interesting that the interface only complains about 1 func which is accessList() types.AccessList, but not other ones i.e. chainID() *big.Int , gas() uint64....

Comment: It complains about the first one it finds, not all.